# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am getting this error while tracking my datakey.. i am not sure why my datakey index is coming out of range.. here is my code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            var dataKeys = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex];
            dataKeys.Value.ToString();
            Label1.Text = "The key field value for the displayed record is " + dataKeys.Value.ToString();
        }
```

Header Part Of the GridView:

```
        </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
         />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function viewProfile(selectedRowIndex, firstName) {
        //alert(firstName);
        //var customGridView = document.getElementById('<%= CustomGridView.ClientID %>');
        var customGridView = document.getElementById('GridView1');
        if (customGridView) {
            var row = customGridView.rows[parseInt(selectedRowIndex) + 1];
            //var cell = customGridView.rows[parseInt(selectedRowIndex) +   1].cells[0];
            //            alert(row.cells[0].innerHTML);
            //            alert(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
            //            alert(row.cells[2].innerHTML);
            //            alert(row.cells[3].innerHTML);
            //            alert(row.cells[4].innerHTML);
            window.open('detatil.aspx?coaid=' + row.cells[1].innerHTML + '&fnomia=' + row.cells[2].innerHTML, "", "scrollbars=no,height=300,width=300");
        }
    }
</script>
```

The error is:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: It looks like `e.Row.RowIndex` isn't set to what you think it is.

Comment: What is the value of e.Row.RowIndex?

Comment: You should post the "header" part of your GridView definition (the <asp:gridview .......... > without the columns definition.

Comment: The var datakeys value is null..

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, that event is fired for header and other non-data-rows. There is a property to know the type of the row. The index of non-data-rows is -1. Add this to check the type of the row:

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: Then filter for RowIndex >= 0 :-) But you should put a breakpoint and watch what row you are getting.

Comment: i am debugging.. the first time, value is -1 then it increments.. it shows error after the datakey is 0.

Comment: On PostBack the DataKeys aren't filled, if I remember correctly. This time are you receiving an out-of-bound exception or a null exception?

Comment: now what to do! :) ? :/ i mean.. any solution you can provide for that?

Comment: @xanatos can you tell me that why have you suggested me to write if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { // do something } what is this check doing?

Comment: @abid Because if you look at the sample in MSDN they do so :-) Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.aspx The event is fired for headers, footers and other "non-data" rows.

Comment: @Xanton can you provide me with the solution of that index out of range error ? :/

Comment: @abid Have you set correctly the property "DataKeyNames" of the GridView to the name of the property with the key?

Comment: DataKeyNames ? i havent used DataKeyNames in my code instead :s. Sorry mate.. i didn`t get you at all.. :/