# Gridview RowIndex returning error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I use this code to get the Row index of a Gridview.

```
            int RowId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["Id"];
```

But it's throwing exception error:

> Error:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataKeyArray.get_Item(Int32 index) at About.btnFollowUp_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Development Phases\ETS_CS_JR\ETS\Private\FollowUp.aspx.cs:line 80

what is the problem in my approach ?

Comment: How many data keys do you have? Probably less than the number of rows ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053291/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle)

Comment: check your `row.RowIndex`. It is either `-1` or more than the `DataKeys` size

Comment: My row.RowIndex is 0. how can I check Datakeys size?

Comment: If there are GridView Data rows there are DataKeys...assuming you set a GridView DataKey to `"Id"`.

Comment: fnostro.... you the champ! I just fixed the problem using your information!